# Jstree create_node in correct place

Tags: jstree

I need to create a node and put it right next to another specific one.

I read the jsTree' doc, and I saw that the "create_node" method has an option, called position, this option should be the position where the node will be inserted, there's the 'last', 'first' and 'name of node' possible value. Looking in google for the answer I've found the 'inside', 'after' and 'before' either.

Last and first can't resolve my problem, but I've tried the 'inside', 'before', 'after', name of node, text on node, node's id, the "#"+node's_id and the index of the node in the children' parent array but none of these have worked.

Do you know how can I create a node after a specific node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. First get the selected node id, then its position. Like this:

```
    var selectedNode = $('#tree').jstree('get_selected', true)[0],
    newPos = $('#'+selectedNode.parent+' li').index( $('#'+selectedNode.id) )+1;
    $('#tree').jstree('create_node', '#'+selectedNode.parent, 'New node', newPos);
```

Check fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/rfvjyLhr/)